# Mysql Nested sub queries unknown column error

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

i have a pretty big query with 2 sub queries. My big query updates an entire column E.
The table looks like this:

```
--------------------------
id  | A      | B    | E  |
--------------------------
1   |  NULL  | NULL |NULL|
--------------------------
2   |  4     | 6    |NULL|
--------------------------
3   |  6     | 9    |NULL|
--------------------------
```

This is my entire query below:

```
 Update mydatabase.mytable  ,
    (SELECT t1.A/AVG(t2.A)
    FROM    mytable t1
    JOIN    mytable t2
    ON      t2.id <= t1.id
    group by t1.id ) AS C,
    (SELECT t1.B/AVG(t2.B)
    FROM    mytable t1
    JOIN    mytable t2
    ON      t2.id <= t1.id
    group by t1.id ) AS D
    SET E = (C+D)/2;
```

I get the error : `Unknown column 'C' in 'field list'`

believe i will also get the same error for D.

My subqueries work and the syntax is correct. i am just unsure of the big query and the update part.

Thanks,

---

**EDIT:**
How can i edit the **ON clause part** of the query above such that i would like the current code to work where id<=14 (which is t2.id <= t1.id as shown above) so when t1 id =14, t2 is all the cumulative id from 1 to 14 as it is now.

**but** for id >14 I would like the ON clause to be **`(t2.id=t1.id>=t1.id-2 and <=t1.id)`**
so when t1 id=15, t2.id should be between 13 and 15.
when t1 id =16, t2.id should be between 14 and 16 and so on.

This is because when i calculate col E for ids after id=14, i am only interested in getting the average of the previous 2 rows for C and D on a moving average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your query using single join only no need to do additional join with conditions to calculate another value

```
Update t  join 
    (SELECT t1.A/AVG(t2.A) C ,t1.B/AVG(t2.B) D
    FROM    t t1
    JOIN    t t2
    ON      t2.id <= t1.id
    group by t1.id ) AS tt
    SET E = (tt.C + tt.D)/2;
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dee2/1)

**Edit for null values**

```
Update t  join 
    (SELECT t1.id ,ifnull(t1.A/AVG(t2.A),0) C ,ifnull(t1.B/AVG(t2.B),0) D
    FROM    t t1
    JOIN    t t2
    ON      t2.id <= t1.id
    group by t1.id ) AS tt
    on(t.id = tt.id)
    SET E = (tt.C + tt.D)/2;
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/285b1/1)

Comment: hmm my col E is still all NULL

Comment: @jenn i have shown [sample demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dee2/1) in my answer and it fills column e, can you also provide fiddle demo for the data set you are trying that would be easier for me

Comment: here is the fiddle link, sorry my first row is all NULL actually. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33b7a/1

Comment: @jenn see my updated answer and updated [*demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/285b1/1)

Comment: Instead of replacing NULL with zeros, can we just leave it as NULL but still populate col E?

Comment: Yes you can leave it as null [as here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8fb0/1) i guess this is what you are asking ?

Comment: @jenn i guess this is new question you should post another question with all the brief and queries and send me the link of your new question thanks

Comment: Here is the link to the new question. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814326/mysql-moving-average-calculation